# How do i have more than one of the same variable?

Tags: c++

im kinda new to c++ programming and for this code im trying to make a code that will give the number of coins used to make a value. I have the following code but i dont know how to make the `pence` variable initialize more than once for each different value. Here is the code:

```
int main ()
{
// Declared variables
double value (3.00), pounds (1.00), pence (0.50),
       pence (0.20), pence (0.10), pence (0.05),
       pence (0.02), pence (0.01);
char again = 'y';
```

I have the rest of the code already but this is the area where i need it to sort out ha.

Comment: Beginner programming class, second lesson: arrays.

Comment: arrays, arrays, arrays

Comment: vectors, vectors, vectors.

Comment: You do not want to use `double`s for this because they introduce inaccuracies. Use integers only.

Comment: pennies, nickels, dimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i have more than one of the same variable?

Simply put, you don't. Variable names are unique, and for good reason.

If you really want a collection of data referred to by the same name, then make an *array* or *vector* with this name and the appropriate number of elements.

```
const double              value = 3.00;
const std::vector<double> coins = { 1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01 };
```

Now you can perform all manner of operations on your vector of available coin denominations.

---

Actually, I'd suggest a `std::set` for this, and don't use floating-point unless you need to. For currency, you don't need to. Use fixed-point.

C++ only supports fixed-point where the number of decimal places is zero (that is, *integers*), but if we count in pennies then this is simple and easy:

```
const int           value = 300;                             // in pennies!
const std::set<int> coins = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };    // in pennies!
```